# How to set class path and connect to DB2 using java

Tags: java, db2, classpath

I don't know how to set the classpath in a java project.

This is the code that I run:

```
try { Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver");
        }  catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Please include Classpath  Where your DB2 Driver is located");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } System.out.println("DB2 driver is loaded successfully");
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rset=null;
        boolean found=false;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2:DB2PDBA","USERID","PASSWORD");
            if (conn != null)
            {
                System.out.println("DB2 Database Connected");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Db2 connection Failed ");
            }
```

and my Error is:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we say put something within classpath, it means:

> ***you should put the related jar files that your app needs to run
>   the entire application somewhere in your project.***

Please follow the link below to create a DB2 application -> [IBM Example about DB2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvjdbas.html)

The only thing you need to do is to:

1. Add this into your project
2. change the credentials and db information
3. add the db2 jdbc jar file to your project

Comment: After including the jar in build path still getting the error-->


java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver

Comment: @Shiv try this -> Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");      The url is different

Comment: Thanks Mehdi....This time driver is loaded but got below error in establishing the connection-
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10389][12245][3.62.57] Failure in loading native library db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2jcct2.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform:  ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null

Comment: @Shiv https://iwm.dhe.ibm.com/sdfdl/v2/regs2/smkane/IDSDIS/Xa.2/Xb.YzLNfpLA2wCCi5LI5hcW9a6q_QZyZ4_a0aqxwNi72xE/Xc.db2_db2driver_for_jdbc_sqlj_v11.1.zip/Xd./Xf.LPr.D1vk/Xg.9952757/Xi.swg-idsdjs/XY.regsrvs/XZ.2CB9-6z1kmuU1Zx97yfrlA9FG7Q/db2_db2driver_for_jdbc_sqlj_v11.1.zip  Try downloading the driver using this link. Then you should try the jars inside the zip file

Comment: @Mehdi- still the same error-
Failure in loading native library db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2jcct2.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform:  ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null

Comment: I can open the DB2 in my system but not able to establish connection through java... then why its saying Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform...it should be compatible when accessing through code also.

Comment: Getting error on executing this statement- -> conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2:Databasename","userid","password");

Comment: @Shiv 1. Use "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" class and db2jcc.jar or db2jcc4.jar (but not db2java.zip) in CLASSPASH. 2. Use url 'jdbc:db2:DB2PDBA' if you installed db2 client and cataloged the DB2PDBA databases under your client DB2 instance ONLY. If you don't use a native db2 client, then use 'jdbc:db2://hostname:port/database' url.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein i am getting below error --> Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform: ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null on executing the statement --> conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2:Databasename","userid","password");

Comment: Thanks guys for helping got my answer here- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21419978, the jre and the db2 should be of same 32 bit

Comment: @Shiv try to find 64bit jar if available, I thought one of the jar inside the zip is 64 bit, that's why I asked you to try them. good luck! anyways you solved your problem already

Comment: Thanks @Mehndi but got one more trouble for oracle data base connection, check here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580341/not-able-to-connect-to-oracle-db-getting-error-as-java-sql-sqlexception-io-exce

Comment: @Shiv okay, please mark this answer as correct answer first if it helps you to solve your problem. Then lets see your new question!