# Not able to connect to Oracle DB getting error as java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Here is the code which i am trying-
ORACLE driver is loaded successfully but getting in get connection that statement-

```
public class OracelConn {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      try {
         try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Please include Classpath  Where your ORACLE Driver is located");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
         }
         System.out.println("ORACLE driver is loaded successfully");
         Connectioncon=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:or0132p.exg.com:1521:OP0132.exg.com", "wsteam", "wsteam");

         Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select TC_ORDER_ID from orders where tc_order_id='0296906379'");
         while (rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getString("TC_ORDER_ID"));

         con.close();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e);
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Basically getting error on-
Connectioncon=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:or0132p.exg.com:1521:OP0132.exg.com","wsteam", "wsteam"); and the error is--> java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: seems I reached to this question late!

Comment: @Mehdi Thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with your `URL` format. Below are supported formats:

If you have an SID, use this (older) format:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@[HOST][:PORT]:SID
```

If you have an Oracle service name, use this (newer) format:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE
```

Source: [orafaq](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC#Thin_driver)

Comment: Thanks @Sukphal... it worked here only the newer format is working as i have the service name...thanks for this-->
("jdbc:oracle:thin:@or0132p.abc.com:1521/OP0132.abc.com", "user", "pwd" ).................                                            i was using the SID one not the Service one as i have the service name